# Evaluating definite integral by products?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function. Show that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pi_{k=1}^n  (1+ \frac 1n f\big( \frac kn\big))=e^{\int_0^1 f(x) dx}   $

My attempt :-

The exponential on RHS compels me to take **ln** both sides but keeping in mind the terms could be negative , I tried the following .

Since the function is continous on $[0,1]$ , there  exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x) | \lt N, \forall x \in [0,1]$

Now let $n\gt N$

Then $1+\frac 1n f\big( \frac k n\big) \gt 0 $ for $1 \le k \le n$

Let $P_n =\Pi_{k=1}^n  (1+ \frac 1n f\big( \frac kn\big))$ be the partial product sequence for $n\gt N$

Then, taking $\ln $ both sides, and using the fact $e^x \ge 1+x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\ln (P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln (1+ \frac 1n f\big( \frac kn\big))\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1n f(\frac kn )$

$\lim \sup  (\ln (P_n)) \le \int_0^1 f(x)dx$

How do I show $\lim\inf (\ln (P_n))\ge \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ ?

Pleae help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac 12 x^2 + O(x^3)$ for $x \to 0$, so that for sufficiently large $n$
$$
\ln \left( 1 + \frac 1n f\left(\frac kn\right)\right) \ge \frac 1n f\left(\frac kn\right)
- \frac 1{n^2} f\left(\frac kn\right)^2
$$
and therefore
$$
\log P_n \ge \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n   f\left(\frac kn\right) - \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n   f\left(\frac kn\right)^2 \, .
$$
Now use the Riemann integral for the first part (as you already did for the upper bound), and use the boundedness of $f$ to show that the second part converges to zero for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Just one question : By $O(x^3) $ , we mean the remaining expression is $x^3 k$ for some constant $k$... right ?

Comment: @user710290: More precisely, $O(x^3)$ denotes a term whose absolute value is $\le k |x|^3$ for some constant $k$.